# Copy file from bamboo user/host to docker container

Tags: docker, bamboo

I am using docker task in my bamboo to build the project. To build the project I need to copy some file from bamboo user to the docker container.

We can copy a file from the host to the docker container by `docker cp` command but how can we do this in bamboo. I am not able to find any useful post. Anyone have any idea or a link to copy a file to docker in bamboo.

I am using run a docker container from image.

Comment: I don't have the bamboo server to try - can you not copy to host location which is also mounted in docker? Alternatively if you have ssh-client (apt-get install openssh-client) you can scp the file to docker container [please not that ssh demon runs as a long running process along with your process whichis not recommenced]

Comment: Where are you running the docker container? On the bamboo agent or on a dedicated docker machine? Maybe the command task can help u out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone else having this issue --

I have used volumes to mount host/bamboo directory in the Docker container and then I can access the file in the Docker container ("Additional arguments" or "Volumes" section).

[image: Bamboo docket task image]